# Mixed effect model for repeated measurements in crossover study using R

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, crossover-study

I am trying to analyze data from a crossover study. The study has two phases and subjects are randomized to received either treatment A or Treatment B first, and then switch to the alternative treatment for phase II The responses are measured at three time points at each phase, baseline, acute, and chronic (so six measurements from each subject).

Here is what my data looks like

[[image]]

I want to see if there is a time, treatment, and time*treatment interaction so I use the `lme`

```r
model = lme(
    response ~ Time*Treatment + Sequence,
    random = ~1 | ID,
    method = "REML",na.action = na.omit, data=example
)
summary(model)
```

> ```
>        AIC      BIC    logLik
>   265.5749 283.3075 -123.7874
>
> Random effects:  Formula: ~1 | ID
>         (Intercept) Residual StdDev:   0.7823654 2.041061
>
> Fixed effects:  response ~ Time * Treatment + Sequence 
>                            Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
> (Intercept)             5.516667 0.7515963 45  7.339933  0.0000
> TimeAcute               0.800000 0.9127902 45  0.876434  0.3854
> TimeChronic            -0.700000 0.9127902 45 -0.766879  0.4472
> TreatmentB              0.200000 0.9127902 45  0.219108  0.8276
> SequenceBA              0.708333 0.7377944  8  0.960069  0.3651
> TimeAcute:TreatmentB   -1.500000 1.2908803 45 -1.161998  0.2514
> TimeChronic:TreatmentB  0.100000 1.2908803 45  0.077467  0.9386 
> Correlation: 
>                        (Intr) TimAct TmChrn TrtmnB SqncBA TmA:TB
> TimeAcute              -0.607                                   
> TimeChronic            -0.607  0.500                            
> TreatmentB             -0.607  0.500  0.500                     
> SequenceBA             -0.393  0.000  0.000  0.000              
> TimeAcute:TreatmentB    0.429 -0.707 -0.354 -0.707  0.000       
> TimeChronic:TreatmentB  0.429 -0.354 -0.707 -0.707  0.000  0.500
>
> Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
>         Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
> -2.26480770 -0.62356253  0.05459007  0.74427691  1.54051708 
>
> Number of Observations: 60 Number of Groups: 10
> ```

the model seems to comparing all data points from acute/chronic to baseline, regardless of treatment. Since I want to whether the treatment A is effective at both time points, I am uncertain if this model is appropriate, or if I should modify my code? I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: How can "acute" & "chronic" be interpreted as time points?